# JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get

```
Match 1: test(testing() tester())

Match 2: theTest()
```

From

`test(testing() tester()) theTest()`

And I am using this RegExp

`/([a-z]+)\((.*)\)/ig`

But is it matching the whole string instead

I figure the problem lies in the `.*` but I cannot figure out what to do

How do I get the RegExp to match the braces without conflicting with inside braces

Here is an [Example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29%5C%28%28.%2a%29%5C%29&input=test%28testing%28%29%20tester%28%29%29%20theTest%28%29)

**EDIT: Since I have found that this is not entirely possible for what am looking for, is there a Function or Methods that could accomplish what I am looking for?**

Comment: So what you're trying to do is get matches with balanced sets of `()`? You can't do that with JavaScript's regular expressions (alone), because it requires state information (knowing how many `(` there have been and so finishing the match when it sees that many `)`). There are some regex engines with extra features to do that, but not JavaScript's.

Comment: If you have a finite set of possibilities (for instance, you only need to handle two or three layers of nesting), you can do it with a fairly complicated alternation...

Comment: It seems like I would have to parse it manually then? Since there isn't a defined amount of iterations deep it will be able to go

Comment: @ Shawn: Yup, I'm afraid so.

Comment: Is there a function or method that I could use to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: @ Shawn: `indexOf` will give you the index of the next `(` in the string, and another will give you the index of the `)` in the string. Then it's loop. Or you could just loop through the characters in the string counting, which is simpler. Most engines support `[]` indexing into strings (`"foo"[0]` is `"f"`), some still require `.charAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. Yes, it is true that the JavaScript regex engine cannot match the *outermost* balanced pair of matching parentheses, but it *can* easily match *innermost* balanced pairs using the following simple regex pattern:

### `reInnerParens`

`/\([^()]*\)/`

This regex can be effectively employed in an iterative manner to match nested balanced parentheses from the inside out. The following useful tested function uses this method to determine if a string has balanced, possibly nested to any depth, matching parentheses:

### `function isBalancedParens(text)`

```js
function isBalancedParens(text) {
    var reInnerParens = /\([^()]*\)/g;
    // Iteratively remove balanced pairs from inside out.
    while (text.search(reInnerParens) !== -1) {
        text = text.replace(reInnerParens, '');
    }
    // Any remaining parens indicate unbalanced pairs.
    if (/[()]/.test(text)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

The above function works by iteratively removing innermost balanced parentheses from the inside out until there are no more matches. If there are any remaining parentheses, then the string contains un-matched parentheses and is not balanced.

A similar iterative technique can be used to solve the problem at hand. First, a regex is needed that matches a balanced pair of parentheses containing at least one inner pair of parentheses, but nested only one level deep. Here it is in free-spacing mode format:

### `reOuterParens`

```js
/* reOuterParens
    # Match outer parens having inner parens one level deep.
    \(          # Outer open paren.
    (           # $1: Contents of outer parens .
      (?:       # One or more nested parens (1 deep).
        [^()]*  # Zero or more non-parens.
        \(      # Inner open paren.
        [^()]*  # Zero or more non-parens.
        \)      # Inner close paren.
      )+        # One or more nested parens (1 deep).
      [^()]*    # Zero or more non-parens.
    )           # End $1: Contents of outer parens .
    \)          # Outer close paren.
*/
var reOuterParens = /\(((?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))+[^()]*)\)/g;
```

The following tested JavaScript function iteratively applies this regex to "hide" all inner parentheses as HTML entities. Once this is completed, then only the desired outermost parentheses remain.

### `function getOutermostParens(text)`

```js
// Match and return all outermost "word(..(..))" patterns from string.
function getOutermostParens(text) {
    var reOuterParens = /\(((?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))+[^()]*)\)/g;
    var results = [];
    // Ensure all (possibly nested) matching parentheses are properly balanced.
    if (!isBalancedParens(text)) return null;
    text = text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') // Temporarily hide html entities.
    // Iteratively hide all parens nested one level deep.
    while (text.search(reOuterParens) !== -1) {
        // Hide nested parens by converting to html entities.
        text = text.replace(reOuterParens,
            function(m0, m1){
                m1 = m1.replace(/[()]/g,
                    function(n0){
                        return {'(':'&#40;', ')': '&#41;'}[n0];
                    });
                return '('+ m1 +')';
            });
    }
    // Match all outermost "word(...)" and load into results array.
    text.replace(/\w+\([^()]*\)/g,
        function(m0){
            m0 = m0.replace(/&#4[01];/g, // Restore hidden parens.
                function(n0){
                    return {'&#40;': '(', '&#41;': ')'}[n0];
                });
            // Restore temporarily hidden html entities.
            m0 = m0.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
            results.push(m0);
            return ''; // Not used.
        });
    return results;
}
```

Note that inner, nested `()` parentheses characters are hidden by replacing them with their HTML entity equivalents (i.e. `&#40;` and `&#41;`), but to do this safely, all HTML entities that may exist in the original string must first be protected. This is done by replacing all `&` with `&amp;` at the beginning of the routine and these are all then restored at the end of the routine.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to take in! Regardless, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split the string on last space ?

```
str.split(/ (?=[^ ]*$)/);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x447m/)

Comment: I'd be surprised if another test case weren't `theTest() test(testing() tester())`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I was thinking the same (I read your comments), but for the string in the question, this seems like the easiest way to get the desired result ?

Answer (score -1):

```
    String i = "test(testing() tester()) theTest()";

    String regex = "\\w+\\(\\w+\\(\\)\\s\\w+\\(\\)\\)|\\w+\\(\\)";
    p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    m = p.matcher(i);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

try using this regex if your text is this much only.

Comment: First, there are easier ways of just doing this for the one input (but the OP has said that the nesting can be arbitrary). Second, the question is about JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Yes the question was about java, but the regex concept will be same in both cases

Answer (score -1):

Use the following regexp:

```
/[a-z]+\(([a-z]+\(\) [a-z]+\(\))*\)/gi
```

Full code:

```
str.match(/[a-z]+\(([a-z]+\(\) [a-z]+\(\))*\)/gi);
```

O/P:

```
["test(testing() tester())", "theTest()"]
```